# Opening a link in CKEditor with one click

Tags: ckeditor

I am using CKEditor, I have put a link into a text. Is it possible to go directly to the link when we click (once) on that link inside CKEditor?

Comment: if you go directly to the link when you click it, how do you edit it if there's any adjustment that you want to make like changing the text, the destination url, formatting..?

Comment: When I double click on linked text, it is opening link editor where I can make adjustment. But if I do single click, it should go to the link.I am not sure if it is possible or not. That's what checking here. Thnx

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this (jQuery required):

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
    $('iframe').contents().click(function(e) {
        if(typeof e.target.href != 'undefined') {
            window.open(e.target.href, 'new' + e.screenX);
        }
    });
});
```

hotfix from https://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/7145#comment:1

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
            $('iframe').contents().click(function (e) {
                if (typeof e.target.href !== 'undefined') {
                    window.open(e.target.href, 'new' + e.screenX);
                } else if (typeof e.currentTarget.activeElement.href !== 'undefined') {
                    window.open(e.currentTarget.activeElement.href, 'new' + e.screenX);
                }
            });
        });
```